# firefox add-on access variable everytime page is loaded

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, content-script

I am writing firefox add-on but I have no idea how to do this (how to store variables between page openings):
When I open page and if var page_count does not exist, I want to create it and set to 1. If I open another page it should count page_count++

I don't know how to set "global" variable in addon (and how to access it later) - it should keep alive between page openings. Any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to use the Simple Storage to store this variables? It's pretty simple and (probably) fast.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-storage

```
 var simpleStorage = require("sdk/simple-storage");
 var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
 simpleStorage.storage.pageCount = 1; //you need to initialize a variable
 tabs.on('open', function onOpen(tab) {
     simpleStorage.storage.pageCount++; //in method
 });
```

Comment: thank you! another way I thought about was to store it as a cookie.